# Group by with ordering - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Lets say I have an array of objects as below and I want to group them by `kick_off` date and order by `kick_off` time

```
[ { id: 32,
    kick_off: 2020-07-07T17:45:00.000Z, 
    home_team: 'Cardiff',
    away_team: 'Blackburn', },
  { id: 33,
    kick_off: 2020-07-08T17:45:00.000Z,
    home_team: 'Fulham',
    away_team: 'Forest',
  },
  { id: 34,
    kick_off: 2020-07-07T17:00:00.000Z,
    home_team: 'Bohemians 1905',
    away_team: 'Mlada Boleslav',
  } 
]
```

So far I have

```
const groupBy = array.reduce(function(r, a) {
    r[a.kick_off] = r[a.kick_off] || [];
    r[a.kick_off].push(a);
    return r;
  }, Object.create(null));
```

This returns

```
{ 'Tue Jul 07 2020 18:45:00 GMT+0100 (BST)':
   [ { id: 32,
       kick_off: 2020-07-07T17:45:00.000Z,
       home_team: 'Cardiff',
       away_team: 'Blackburn',
     } 
   ],
  'Wed Jul 08 2020 18:45:00 GMT+0100 (BST)':
   [ { id: 33,
       kick_off: 2020-07-08T17:45:00.000Z,
       home_team: 'Fulham',
       away_team: 'Forest',
     }
   ],
 'Tue Jul 07 2020 18:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)':
   [ { id: 34,
       kick_off: 2020-07-07T17:00:00.000Z,
       home_team: 'Bohemians 1905',
       away_team: 'Mlada Boleslav',
     }
   ] 
}
```

I know why it groups like this, it's because the kick_off times are different for games on the same day (I have tried making each kick off time the same and it does group correctly)

How would I group by day and order by time with the object I have

Any links to resources or an explanation would be very useful to learn from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort in advance and take only the day part for grouping.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: 32, kick_off: '2020-07-07T17:45:00.000Z', home_team: 'Cardiff', away_team: 'Blackburn' }, { id: 33, kick_off: '2020-07-08T17:45:00.000Z', home_team: 'Fulham', away_team: 'Forest' }, { id: 34, kick_off: '2020-07-07T17:00:00.000Z', home_team: 'Bohemians 1905', away_team: 'Mlada Boleslav' }],
    groupBy = array
        .sort((a, b) => a.kick_off.localeCompare(b.kick_off))
        .reduce(function(r, a) {
            let day = a.kick_off.slice(0, 10);
            r[day] = r[day] || [];
            r[day].push(a);
            return r;
        }, Object.create(null));
  
console.log(groupBy);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you, I had to change the sort to a.kick_off - b.kick_off as they where timestamps and not strings (though when i converted toString the ordering was still off), anyway, thats not the point, thank you very much for your answer and helping me

Comment: you need an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant string for sorting by string. otherwise take epoch and the delta of it.